# why the Winform BegineInvoke is too slow?

Tags: c, winforms

Why the Winform BegineInvoke is too slow?

Here is the code that i make winform treeview and add nodes.
I do this in main thread, which is in form's constructor.

```
//Create many tree nodes

TreeNode first = new TreeNode("First");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  TreeNode secondChild = new TreeNode("Second" + i);
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
  {
     TreeNode thirdChild = new TreeNode("Third" + j);
     for (int k = 0; k < 3000; ++k)
     {
       TreeNode fourthChild = new TreeNode("Fourth" + i);
       thirdChild.Nodes.Add(fourthChild);
     }
     secondChild.Nodes.Add(thirdChild);
  }
  first.Nodes.Add(secondChild);
}

//Measure the time add nodes to treeview
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Start");
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node2); //add to treeview
Console.WriteLine("End : " + watch.Elapsed.ToString());
```

It takes under 0.1 seconds. It is not slow.
But If i make new thread and do same things in new thread, then it takes over 40 seconds.

I use BeginInvoke to add nodes to treeview outside of main thread.

```
if (treeView1.InvokeRequired == true)
   treeView1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
   treeView1.Nodes.Add(first)));
```

Why the begin invoke is very slow?

And i also used async method instead to do this.

```
public TreeNode GetTreeNode()
{

  TreeNode rootTree = null;

  rootTree = new TreeNode("First");
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      TreeNode secondChild = new TreeNode("Second" + i);
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
      {
         TreeNode thirdChild = new TreeNode("Third" + j);
         for (int k = 0; k < 3000; ++k)
         {
             TreeNode fourthChild = new TreeNode("Fourth" + i);
             thirdChild.Nodes.Add(fourthChild);
         }
         secondChild.Nodes.Add(thirdChild);
      }
     rootTree.Nodes.Add(secondChild);
   }

    return rootTree;
}

public async void AddNodeToTreeView()
{
            TreeNode node = null;
            Task<TreeNode> task = Task<TreeNode>.Factory.StartNew(() => node = GetTreeNode());
            await task;

            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            Console.WriteLine("End : " + watch.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

And i called AddNodeToTreeView method. But the elapsed time was slow too.

Why async and begin invoke is too slow? How should i solve this problem?

Comment: It's not slow. You are *not* adding anything from another thread. You can't modify *any* UI control from another thread. You are still on the UI thread. If that thread is busy, the call to `BeginInvoke` will wait until the UI thread is free

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for answering. Yes i must add only ui thread. But why the begin invoke is slow? It is same that between add nodes in main thread and use begin invoke in other thread.

Comment: Why do you want to load the treeview "in the background" anyway? If you have a lot of data the trick is to *not* load what can't be displayed. This is available through virtual scrolling, data virtualization techniques that are already available on Windows Forms.

Comment: What other thread? `BeginInvoke` on a UI control says: "run this code on the UI thread".

Comment: I have another more logic like networking or merging tree with another tree and so on. It has a little overhead. So i must do this in another thread because i don't want to stop ui (main) thread.

Comment: Well, 'other thread' means that a working thread except ui(main) thread. It will do networking , make trees , merge trees and so on.

Comment: Like any `async/await` example. First, you don't need `BeginInvoke` at all, you can use `async/await` and keep modifying the UI after each asynchronous operation. Second, pushing calls from one thread to another will always be slow. *Don't* do it without a reason. If you want to add nodes for 10 items, call a method that accepts an array of items and adds them at once. Don't make 10 cross-thread calls

Comment: Hum... i convert this to async method but it is slow too.

Comment: *What* is too slow? You still haven't posted any relevant code. And using `async` doesn't make any cross-threaded calls. When you write `var result=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(..); treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(result));` the second line is already back in the UI thread

Comment: I fixed my question and i add detail about my async trying.
It is also slow when i add treenode to treeview by async method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question. If you're just looking to modify a control off the UI thread you can try something like this with a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
                Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                {
                      // Anything you want do.
                });
```

Comment: thanks, but it also block ui thread when the invoke action has overhead.